# Ubuntu Server Mercurial Set Up issues

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, version-control, mercurial

Can you please help me. I followed all the steps in this blog [mercurial tutorial](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/mercurial-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-with-web-access/?contact-form-id=428&contact-form-sent=131054&_wpnonce=b04cc57329#contact-form-428) but when i got to, ipadress/mercurial. I see, the below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# # An example hgweb CGI script, edit as necessary 
# See also http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories 
# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb') 
config = "/mercurial/hgweb.config" 
# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide 
# (consult "installed modules" path from 'hg debuginstall'):
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python/lib") 
# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
# import cgitb; 
cgitb.enable() 
from mercurial import demandimport; 
demandimport.enable() 
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi 
application = hgweb(config) wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

The only difference I ran into was cd /etc/apache2/sites-available sudo nano default. I didnt have default but 000default, but i added default. I am using ubuntu14

Can anyone help? I am new to both ubuntu and mercurial.

Logging into the link ipaddress/mercurial is supposed to show me the current repositories that I have access to, where I can push and pull data, but I see only the above.

Comment: First, please learn how to use the question editor. Online help is available. Code should be marked up to show properly. Second, please clearly tell us what your problem really is: I currently see _"I see the below. [...] Can anyone help?"_ Help with _what_?

Comment: Thanks Lutz, its my first time using stackoverflow as well. I do apologise for the misuse. I have updated the blog to clear articulate my problem.